# Angularjs using service to pass a parameter to a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm fetching a Json with a factory "chapters", so I get the value of the property "*json_file*" which is another json file that I need to fetch dynamically with the factory "contents". I just need to pass the parameter "*json_file*" to the second factory, but I get an undefined value.
Maybe I need a service?

This is the first json file:

**structure.js**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Introduction",
        "pages": [
            {
                "title": "Buongiorno",
                "type" : "standard",
                "json_file" : "cover_1"
            },
            {
                "title": "Introduction",
                "type" : "standard",
                "json_file" : "cover_1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Storytelling",
        "pages": [
            {
                "title": "Italian Design & Swiss Watchmaking Expertise",
                "type" : "standard",
                "json_file" : "cover_1"
            },
            {
                "title": "Interaction",
                "type" : "standard",
                "json_file" : "cover_1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the **controller.js**

```
var bControllers = angular.module('bControllers',[]);

bControllers.controller('structureCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams,chapters,contents){

    $scope.indexChapter = 0;    
    $scope.indexPage = 0;   

    chapters.list(function(chapters) {
        $scope.chapters = chapters;
        $scope.pages = [];
        $scope.json_file = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.chapters, function(chapters,index){
            angular.forEach(chapters.pages, function(page,index2){
                $scope.pages.push(page);
                $scope.json_file.push(page.json_file);
            })
        });

        $scope.currentJson = $scope.chapters[$scope.indexChapter].pages[$scope.indexPage].json_file;

        console.log('json-file:'+$scope.currentJson);

        return $scope.currentJson;
    });

    contents.find($scope.currentJson, function(content) {
        $scope.content = content;
     });

});
```

And this is the **factory.js**

```
var bFactory = angular.module('bFactory',[]);

bFactory.factory('chapters', function($http){
  return {
        list: function (callback){
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'json/structure.json',
            cache: true
          }).success(callback);
        }
   }
});

bFactory.factory('contents', function($http){

    return{

        find:function(json_file, callback){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'json/'+json_file+'.json',
                cache: true
             }).success(callback);
        }

    }

})
```

Comment: Don't pass callbacks to service methods. Return promises instead. And use chaining. You're trying to pass currentJson to contents.find() immediately after you've called the first service. You need to do that in the callback of the first service call, since this callback is called much later, asynchronously, when the http response has come back from the backend. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/. Also note that success() doesn't even exist anymore in the latest version of angularjs.

Comment: I know that success() is deprecated but if I don't do that I can't print the result on the template. I'd prefer to use promise but how can I print results?

Comment: You would know if you had read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/